# Is fair to compare Dirichlet to a Multivariate Beta regression?

Tags: bayesian, beta-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, beta-regression, dirichlet-regression

I am conducting some analysis on my data I found a strange behavior and would greatly appreciate some guidance or suggestions.

I am trying to investigate the effect of a categorical variable (**cl**) to three percentages that sum 1 (**M**). Naturally, I conducted a *dirichlet regression* on my dataset and a multivariate *beta regression*, but when compared using *loo* the *beta regression* presented a significantly better fit the data than the *dirichlet*.

$M \sim Dirichlet([1, \beta_a * tb, \beta_b * tb])$

or

$M1 \sim Beta(1, \beta_a * tb)$

$M2 \sim Beta(1, \beta_b * tb)$

$M3 \sim Beta(1, \beta_c * tb)$

Strangely, the predicted variables sum varies between 50% to 150% which is nonsense. However, the fitted variables sum varies 95% to 105% that is an acceptable error.

Is it fair to compare the models? or due to the natural constraints of a *Dirichlet* model it yields worst fit than a *multivariate beta regression*?

Comment: Why would you assume that three independent probabilities will sum to 1?

Comment: To follow on to @Tim's note (+1) - if you remove the constraint that the probabilities sum to 1, you'll naturally get a better fit - the unconstrained fit can't be worse than the constrained one, after all!